# Is there an Eclipse shortcut to sort members by modifier?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for a shortcut, preference or plugin in Eclipse which will sort Java members by visibility modifier.  Specifically, I'm looking for the class to be sorted like this:

```
public someClass {
   //public variables go first followed by 
   //protected and default variables and lastly
   //private variables

   //public methods above
   //proteted and default methods with
   //private methods at the bottom
}
```

I'm not fussed about alphabetically, only the visibility modifier.

Comment: This is more of a workaround: You can drag methods, fields and types in the outline view to change their order as long as that list is not sorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Window->preferences->Java->Appearance->Members Sort

Comment: You have indeed a checkbox called `Sort members in same category by visibility`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.  This combined with the `Sort Members` command in `Perferences->General->Keys` allowed me to set a custom key binding for this.

Answer (score 3):

`(Alt-Shift-S),` Sort Members.  A pop Up opens and you can select whatever you want.

I have no reputation that's why I answered

Comment: Cool shortcut ALT-SHIFT-S :-)

Answer (score -2):

```java
public static void main(String []args) {
    int arr [] = {50,10,20,30,40,1,5,3,4,2};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question.