# Eclipse feature to arrange a class file?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, formatting

Eclipse has tons of features, i'm wondering if this one exsists? Or if any shortcut ways of doing it exist?

I want to arrange my class data into Variables, Constructors, Methods in that flow(Top to Bottom)

Further refined I would like to arrange by access level(pub, private, protected) and type - void or methods that return. The same for Vars - access level and type.

Any ideas. I mean I try to keep my code as tidy as possible. But would be nice to kind of format a class that perhaps I havent written that is messy.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098205/is-there-an-eclipse-shortcut-to-sort-members-by-modifier

Comment: A word of caution: Changing the order of members may change the behaviour of your program. For instance, field initializers are executed in declaration order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go the preferences screen and then go to Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order you can configure the sort order for members.

Next just right click when you have a file open and go to Source -> Sort members

Answer (score 1):

Under Preferences choose Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order. This allows you to set the order of members within a class when you use the Sort Members action.