# Eclipse - format java class/interface declaration

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

In Eclipse, is it possible to set an order for a class/interface declarations? I'd like to have an order similar to this

1. Constructors
2. Factory methods
3. Instance methods
4. Static methods
5. Inner classes
6. Instance variables
7. Static variables
8. Constants
9. Static initializers

So, for example, class constructors should be placed always before methods, factory methods always before instance methods, and so on. 
I'd like to have something similar to Ctrl+F, which in change place all the various part of the source code in the right order.
If it is not possible, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Eclipse has a strong format facilities. Start from the default formatting. Select you code and press Ctrl-F.

If standard formatting is not good for you you can customize it: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I'm asking a different thing; maybe my question wasn't so clear. I modified it now, let me know if it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a partial solution here
[How to specify the order of class members when formatting in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198177/how-to-specify-the-order-of-class-members-when-formatting-in-eclipse)
and here
[Eclipse feature to arrange a class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107944/eclipse-feature-to-arrange-a-class-file?rq=1)

So, I'm actually using this format under Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order

[image]

and to reorder the declarations inside class I'm just using Source -> Sort members.

However, the solution is only partial because I can't distinguish factory methods and constants. I can understand that can be difficult to identify factory methods; at the same time I don't think it is so difficult to identify a `final` declaration and sort members by them.